# zend framework inner functionality step by step

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to zend frame work and I want to know  innner functionality step by step. Please try to help me

Comment: What do you mean by inner functionality? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Sorry, this question is way too general. If you want to learn Zend Framework, then start on their website with their Quick Start Guide and other reference materials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get used to standard MVC and some of the specifics of ZF-bootstrapping (Zend_Application, Application Resources, Controller Plugins, etc), the request life-cycle is actually pretty straightforward, though it may seem like black-magic, at first. At least, it sure did to me, especially bootstrapping resources and registering paths for helpers; scripts; custom elements, filters, validators, scripts, etc. ;-)

I think this [Zend DevZone article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/11978) explains the life-cycle pretty well, though it is focused more on plugins and doesn't really address resource bootstrapping as much as I would like. Referenced in that article is a very clean, but a little bit scary, [chart of the request life-cycle](http://nethands.de/download/zenddispatch_en.pdf).

This [slideshare presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/polleywong/zend-framework-dispatch-workflow) discusses the life-cycle, as well.

Comment: means, I want to know the flow of zend framework, like how the request is routed and how the response is dispatched

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase your question then, as it currently makes no reference to these features!

Comment: Routing - mapping a url to a (module, controller, action) triplet is pretty well explained in the [routing docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html). "How" the request is dispatched is probably best understood by looking at the code itself, starting at `Zend_Controller_Front::dispatch()`, following through `Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard::dispatch()`. That's how I got at least a modest grip on it.

Answer (score 3):

Great, oft recommended places to start are as follows:

[The Zend Framework Quick Start Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html)

[Rob Allen's Zend Framework Tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/)

Rob Allen's guide will take you through building a sample application, where you will learn key concepts and should then be ready to start your own project.